# Approipriate use of rfe with xgboost classifier

Tags: feature-selection

I have an imbalanced data set with about 6000 features. I am using the XGBoost classifier to classify the labels. However, due to the large number of features, I am opting for rfe function to select an appropriate number of features (to prevent overfitting).

Is there a less expensive feature selection alternative to rfe? I would like a demo maybe...

I am pretty stuck right now and I am not sure how to do this properly.

Here is my code:

```
y=training['prediction']
x=training.drop(['prediction'],axis=1)

imp_mean =SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy ='most_frequent')
impx=pd.DataFrame(imp_mean.fit_transform(x))
imptest=pd.DataFrame(imp_mean.fit_transform(test))

x=impx
test=imptest

model =XGBClassifier()


feat_selector = RFE(model,10)

feat_selector = feat_selector.fit(x, y)


f =feat_selector.get_support
x = df[df.columns[f]]

x_train,x_val,y_train,y_val = train_test_split(x,y,test_size =0.30,random_state=1)

scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_val=scaler.fit_transform(x_val)

abc =XGBClassifier(max_depth=2,n_estimators=50)

abc.fit(x_train,y_train)

y_pred =abc.predict(x_val)
print(accuracy_score(y_val,y_pred))
print(confusion_matrix(y_val,y_pred))
```

Thanks.

Comment: did your XGB come from sklearn?

Comment: I suggest SHAP-HYPETUNE: https://github.com/cerlymarco/shap-hypetune... A python package for simultaneous Hyperparameters Tuning and Features Selection for Gradient Boosting Models